# Python Turtle Graphics Missing Pixels from Right-Hand Side and Bottom of Screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In this simple Python Turtle Graphics example, the furthest position available to click for the right hand-side is `245` and for the bottom of the window `-245`. For the left and top, `-250` and `250` are possible So there are some pixels missing from the right and bottom of the window. Adding 5 to the width and height increases the size in the left and up directions, so doesn't fix the problem.

Can someone explain what is going on here please? Is there a way to specify exact dimensions for the turtle window?

[image]

```
import turtle

def click(x, y):
    print(x, y)

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.onclick(click)

turtle.done()
```